# If i make a single database table for all the inbox messages in an application, will it slow down with the passage of time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have made a table Messages in SQL Server 2008R2 to store all the send receive messages with in an application, so all the chat messages will be stored in that single table for all the users. Will it become slow with the passage of time as there will be many records of many users. What is the best way to handle this? also for your information i have used Entity Framework technique for SQL Server in .net.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, yes, it may become slow.

In reality - if you use indexes and have 100M rows (or less) in the table, it should not be a big deal for normal operations (e.g. displaying recently sent messages to the user etc.). In that case, indexes will be needed especially on `date` and `userId` fields.

Here are some details about how to use indexes: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx

Comment: what should i do with date? or Should i break the table into two parts?

Comment: No, no, just create an index above them. I have edited the post and added some details of how to use indexes.

Comment: I have used foreignkey, primary key and relationships in database tables. I opened your link but i am unable to understand how index will be performed on my table.

Comment: Well, I don't see any structure of your tables in the question, so as long as you don't provide them, I won't be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking here about chat messages, which lets me think that you are not talking about email messages, where there is typically a sender and one or multiple receiver(s).

I will then advise you to add a 'chat sessions' table, where each chat will be identified with a unique identifier. All chat messages will then have a chatId field, so you can easily find all messages sent during the chat session.

Other pertaining info related to your chat can then be retrieved from your messages table, like:

- who was in the chat (group by userId for chatId = )
- when did the chat start (minimum of messageTime)
- etc.

Your database ***will not*** become slow as long as your tables are correctly indexed, and your hardware is set to fit your database needs.

Anyway, This is definitely the best way to handle such a situation.